# How to redefine a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am attempting to create a settings page, which relies on variables to check whether to do something or not to do it.
Here is my code at the current moment:

```js
function affectedsetting() {
  var setting = 1;
  if (setting === 1) {
    runfunction();
  } else {

  }
}

function changesetting() {
  var setting = '1';
}

function changesetting2() {
  var setting = '0';
}
```

Comment: The variable needs to be declared in the global scope so that all the functions can access it. You're declaring it local to each function, so they don't share it.

Answer (score 1):

The variable needs to be declared and initialized outside of the functions. And when you want to update it, you should not re-declare it, since that will make it a local variable within that function, it won't update the global variable.

Also, boolean settings should be `true/false`, not `1/0`.

```js
let setting = true;

function affectedsetting() {
  if (setting) {
    runfunction();
  }
}

function changesetting() {
  setting = true;
}

function changesetting2() {
  setting = false;
}
```